# Segmentation fault while reading water flow sensor

Tags: gpio

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
#Declaration of pin
flowSen1=29
flowSen2=31
flowSen3=7
flowSen4=11
tankIn=12
tankOut=13



cali_flowSen1=4.5
cali_flowSen2=4.5
cali_flowSen3=4.5
cali_flowSen4=4.5
cali_tankIn=4.5
cali_tankOut=4.5

global pulsecount_flowSen1
global pulsecount_flowSen2
global pulsecount_flowSen3
global pulsecount_flowSen4
global pulsecount_tankIn
global pulsecount_tankOut

pulsecount_flowSen1=0
pulsecount_flowSen2=0
pulsecount_flowSen3=0
pulsecount_flowSen4=0
pulsecount_tankIn=0
pulsecount_tankOut=0

GPIO.setup(flowSen1,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(flowSen2,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(flowSen3,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(flowSen4,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(tankIn,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(tankOut,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

#Pulse Counter funtion for each Flowsensor
def pulse_flowSen1(flowSen1):
    global pulsecount_flowSen1
    pulsecount_flowSen1=pulsecount_flowSen1+1

def pulse_flowSen2(flowSen2):
    global pulsecount_flowSen2
    pulsecount_flowSen2=pulsecount_flowSen2+1

def pulse_flowSen3(flowSen3):
    global pulsecount_flowSen3
    pulsecount_flowSen3=pulsecount_flowSen3+1

def pulse_flowSen4(flowSen4):
    global pulsecount_flowSen4
    pulsecount_flowSen4=pulsecount_flowSen4+1

def pulse_tankIn(tankIn):
    global pulsecount_tankIn
    pulsecount_tankIn=pulsecount_tankIn+1

def pulse_tankOut(tankOut):
    global pulsecount_tankOut
    pulsecount_tankOut=pulsecount_tankOut+1

GPIO.add_event_detect(flowSen1,GPIO.FALLING,callback=pulse_flowSen1)
GPIO.add_event_detect(flowSen2,GPIO.FALLING,callback=pulse_flowSen2)
GPIO.add_event_detect(flowSen3,GPIO.FALLING,callback=pulse_flowSen3)
GPIO.add_event_detect(flowSen4,GPIO.FALLING,callback=pulse_flowSen4)
GPIO.add_event_detect(tankIn,GPIO.FALLING,callback=pulse_tankIn)
GPIO.add_event_detect(tankOut,GPIO.FALLING,callback=pulse_tankOut)

while(True):
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(flowSen1)
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(flowSen2)
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(flowSen3)
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(flowSen4)
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(tankIn)
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(tankOut)

    flowRate1=pulsecount_flowSen1/cali_flowSen1
    flowRate2=pulsecount_flowSen2/cali_flowSen2
    flowRate3=pulsecount_flowSen3/cali_flowSen3
    flowRate4=pulsecount_flowSen4/cali_flowSen4
    flowRateTankIn=pulsecount_tankIn/cali_tankIn
    flowRateTankOut=pulsecount_tankOut/cali_tankOut

    print "FR1=",round(flowRate1,3)," FR2=",round(flowRate2,3)," FR3=",round(flowRate3,3)," FR4=",round(flowRate4,3)," Tin=",round(flowRateTankIn,3)," Tout=",round(flowRateTankOut,3)

    pulsecount_flowSen1=0
    pulsecount_flowSen2=0
    pulsecount_flowSen3=0
    pulsecount_flowSen4=0
    pulsecount_tankIn=0
    pulsecount_tankOut=0

    GPIO.add_event_detect(flowSen1,GPIO.FALLING,callback=pulse_flowSen1)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(flowSen2,GPIO.FALLING,callback=pulse_flowSen2)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(flowSen3,GPIO.FALLING,callback=pulse_flowSen3)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(flowSen4,GPIO.FALLING,callback=pulse_flowSen4)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(tankIn,GPIO.FALLING,callback=pulse_tankIn)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(tankOut,GPIO.FALLING,callback=pulse_tankOut)
```

Comment: You should probably add some debug printout lines and/or run a debugger on it. Checkout `pdb`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the question is why does it segfault.  I guess it's because you are not using the library as it is intended to be used (as far as I am aware).

Change

```py
while(True):
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(flowSen1)
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(flowSen2)
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(flowSen3)
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(flowSen4)
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(tankIn)
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(tankOut)

    flowRate1=pulsecount_flowSen1/cali_flowSen1
    flowRate2=pulsecount_flowSen2/cali_flowSen2
    flowRate3=pulsecount_flowSen3/cali_flowSen3
    flowRate4=pulsecount_flowSen4/cali_flowSen4
    flowRateTankIn=pulsecount_tankIn/cali_tankIn
    flowRateTankOut=pulsecount_tankOut/cali_tankOut

    print "FR1=",round(flowRate1,3), ...

    pulsecount_flowSen1=0
    pulsecount_flowSen2=0
    pulsecount_flowSen3=0
    pulsecount_flowSen4=0
    pulsecount_tankIn=0
    pulsecount_tankOut=0

    GPIO.add_event_detect(flowSen1,GPIO.FALLING,callback=pulse_flowSen1)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(flowSen2,GPIO.FALLING,callback=pulse_flowSen2)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(flowSen3,GPIO.FALLING,callback=pulse_flowSen3)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(flowSen4,GPIO.FALLING,callback=pulse_flowSen4)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(tankIn,GPIO.FALLING,callback=pulse_tankIn)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(tankOut,GPIO.FALLING,callback=pulse_tankOut)
```

to

```py
while(True):
    time.sleep(1)

    flowRate1=pulsecount_flowSen1/cali_flowSen1
    flowRate2=pulsecount_flowSen2/cali_flowSen2
    flowRate3=pulsecount_flowSen3/cali_flowSen3
    flowRate4=pulsecount_flowSen4/cali_flowSen4
    flowRateTankIn=pulsecount_tankIn/cali_tankIn
    flowRateTankOut=pulsecount_tankOut/cali_tankOut

    print "FR1=",round(flowRate1,3), ...

    pulsecount_flowSen1=0
    pulsecount_flowSen2=0
    pulsecount_flowSen3=0
    pulsecount_flowSen4=0
    pulsecount_tankIn=0
    pulsecount_tankOut=0
```

Comment: Very Thank you. It is working by changing the code as suggested above.

Comment: There is a chance that the callback increment is interrupted by the setting to zero, so that it isn't set to zero properly.  If that's a concern you could do temp = pulsecount_flowSen1; count = temp - oldcount_flowSen1; oldcount_flowSen1 = temp.